# Create matrix with numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to create a matrix with `M` rows and `N` columns. The increment along the columns are always `1`, whilst the increment in rows are a constant value, `c`. For example, to create this matrix:

[image]

The number of rows are 4, the number of columns are 2 and the shift between rows: `c = 8`. One way to perform this could be:

```
# Indices of columns
coord_x = np.arange(0, 2) 
# Indices of rows
coord_y = np.arange(1, 37, 9)
# Creates 2 matrices with the coordinates 
x, y = np.meshgrid(coord_x, coord_y)
# To perform the shift between columns
idx_left = x + y
```

And the output is:

```
print(idx_left)

[[ 1  2]
 [10 11]
 [19 20]
 [28 29]]
```

Can I perform this without the adding `idx_left = x + y`?. I've already seen other functions but I don't find any that considers a shift along the rows and columns...

Comment: Its not clear what you want. Are you looking for an approach that uses meshgrid? or are you exploring an approach that only increments a array along an axis

Comment: Hi @AkshaySehgal I'm looking a way to create a matrix with increment in `x axis` and `y axis`. At the moment the easy way that I've found is using `meshgrid` and the final step with the addition of both axis.

Comment: I have updated multiple ways you can do this in my answer. do check and let me know if that solves your question.

Comment: `meshgrid` with sparse True produces `x,y` like the ones used the answer's `broadcasting` examlle.  Computationally there isn't much difference in these alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Stride tricks

You can use `np.lib.stride_tricks` for this purpose.

```
arr = np.arange(1,100)
shape = (4,2)
strides = (arr.strides[0]*9,arr.strides[0]*1) #8 bytes with 9 steps on axis=0, 8bytes with 1 step on axis=1

np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [10, 11],
       [19, 20],
       [28, 29]])
```

Another example with 2 shift on axis=0 and 3 shift on axis=1.

```
arr = np.arange(1,100)
shape = (4,2)
strides = (arr.strides[0]*2,arr.strides[0]*3) #8bytes * 2shift on axis=0, 8bytes*3shift on axis=1

np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

```
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 3,  6],
       [ 5,  8],
       [ 7, 10]])
```

#### Broadcasting

You could simply do this the same way you are doing without meshgrids only using broadcasting as well -

```
#Your original example
coord_x = np.arange(0, 2, 1)  #start, stop, step
coord_y = np.arange(1, 37, 9)
coord_x[None,:] + coord_y[:,None]
```

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [10, 11],
       [19, 20],
       [28, 29]])
```

#### Linspace

You could use linspace if you have extreme limits. So, in your case, you can create a 4 row array from (1,2) to (28,29).

```
np.linspace((1,2),(28,29),4)
```

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [10., 11.],
       [19., 20.],
       [28., 29.]])
```

#### Mgrid

Mgrid is more convenient than mesh grid for your purpose. You can do -

```
np.mgrid[0:2:1, 1:37:9].sum(0).T
```

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [10, 11],
       [19, 20],
       [28, 29]])
```

Comment: Thx! All the provided solutions works perfectly, but linspace I think is the better way  (in my case I have very large matrices...)